# c# - Create and upload csv file to ADLS

Tags: c#, csv, filestream, azure-data-lake, memorystream

I am trying to create a .csv file to upload into ADLS using [DataLakeFileClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-datalake/datalakefileclient?view=azure-node-latest) and [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-5.0). It works fine but the csv file has a garbage value after each letter in the csv. (I can see those as 'NUL's when I download and open the file in notepad++).

Here is my code:

```html
 DataLakeFileClient fileClient = new DataLakeFileClient(new
  Uri($"https://{accountName}.dfs.core.windows.net/{container}/{directory}/{filename}"), credential); 
UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(100))
    {
    byte[] colString = uniEncoding.GetBytes("a,b,c,d,e,f");
    memStream.Write(colString, 0, colString.Length);
    
    memStream.WriteByte(0x0A);
    
    byte[] dataString = uniEncoding.GetBytes(string.Join(",", "val1","val2","val3","val4","val5","val6"));
    memStream.Write(dataString, 0, dataString.Length);
    memStream.Position = 0;
    fileClient.Upload(memStream); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your LF (0x0A) is one byte instead of 2.
Add after it another byte:

```
memStream.WriteByte(0x0A);
memStream.WriteByte(0x0);
```